# Enter Croatia with "Temporary Residence Permit" of France

Tags: visa, croatia

Up to March I had a 5 Year Schengen Visa, which the local French prefecture extended with a 3 months "Temporary Residence Permit" due to current circumstances.

I am a South African Citizen and my wife and daughter are both French. Would I be able to travel to Croatia with this visa by airplane from Paris?

Comment: Are you wanting to travel to Croatia for vacation/visit, or to live?

Comment: @Midavalo the purpose of travel is not relevant.